# Safely unwrapping optional values and add it to Alamofire parameters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parameters, alamofire

I have a computed property of type Parameters in my APIRouter

```
// MARK: - Parameters
    private var parameters: Parameters? {
        switch self {
        case .searchForDoctors(let doctorsFilter):
            var params: Parameters = ["main_category_id": doctorsFilter.0, "page": doctorsFilter.1, "specialty_id": doctorsFilter.2, "city_id": doctorsFilter.3, "region_id": doctorsFilter.4, "name": doctorsFilter.5, "company_id": doctorsFilter.6, "order_by": doctorsFilter.7]
            return params
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

some values in the Typealias called doctorsFilter are optional.
currently I have a warning asking me to provide default value for the optional values, and I don't want to provide default values , I want to check if the value exist to add it, otherwise i will not add the key and the value

**how can I safely unwrap the optional values and add it to the parameters dictionary  with out saying if let for all optional values?**
example:

```
if let specialtyID = doctorsFilter.2 {
    params["specialty_id"] = specialtyID
}
```

I don't want to unwrap it this way as I will check for all optional values and it will take more lines of code

**EDIT:-**
**the DoctorsFilter type is documented, when I initialize an instance of type DoctorsFilter the autocomplete tells me which of them is what, I I've thought about making the DoctorsFilter class before but I'm looking for another way if any, maybe a built in reserved word can handle the whole situation! , I want to make it simple as much as possible.
making a function that handles the dictionary and returns it in DoctorsFilter class is an option. I'm thinking of adding this function to the APIRouter, is it fine to add it there? is it the rule of the APIRouter to handle the parameters ? or the APIRouter just interested in taking the parameters and will not handle it ?**

Comment: I think you need to start from turning a `doctorsFilter` into a _normal_ type: having a septuple (e.g. `doctorsFilter.0`, `doctorsFilter.3`) is bad, having septuple with optionals is even worse. Do you even know which of them is what? And maybe you do, but in a year from now who can maintain such code? Once your `doctorsFilter` is a normal type, that normal type can also have a function (or computer property) that returns `Parameters` with only available values

Comment: @KirilS. well, the DoctorsFilter type is documented, when I initialize an instance of type DoctorsFilter the autocomplete tells me which of them is what, I I've thought about your 'normal type' before but I'm looking for another way if any, maybe a built in reserved word can handle the whole situation! , I want to make it simple as much as possible. so I appreciate your response but your suggest will be my last option

Comment: @KirilS. question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "one line" solution, but you can use `KeyPath`s to reduce the series of `if let ...` statements down to a loop.

Start by creating a struct for your filter rather than using a tuple.

To facilitate this, we define a protocol for `Parameterable` - This protocol requires a dictionary that maps parameter names (`String`) to the property (`KeyPath`) that holds that parameter name as well as a function to return the parameters dictionary.

```
protocol Parameterable {
    var paramNames: [String:KeyPath<Self,String?>] {get}
    func parameters() -> [String:Any]
}
```

Use an extension to create a default implementation of the `parameters()` function, as the code will be the same for all `Parameterable`s.  It iterates over the dictionary entries and uses the associated `KeyPath` to access the relevant property and put it in the output dictionary.  If a given property is `nil` then it simply isn't added to the output dictionary, because that is how dictionaries work.  No need to explicitly check.

(If you import Alamofire then you can use the `typedef` `Parameters` where I have used `[String:Any]`)

```
extension Parameterable {
    func parameters() -> [String:Any] {
        var parameters = [String:Any]()
    
        for (paramName,keypath) in self.paramNames {
            parameters[paramName]=self[keyPath:keypath]
        }
        return parameters
    }
}
```

Use this protocol to create a `DoctorsFilter` implementation:

```
struct DoctorsFilter: Parameterable {
    var mainCategoryId: String?
    var page: String?
    var specialtyId: String?
    var cityID: String?
    var regionId: String?
    var name: String?
    var companyId: String?
    var orderBy: String?

    let paramNames:[String:KeyPath<Self,String?>] = [ 
    "main_category_id":\.mainCategoryId,
    "page":\.page,
    "specialty_id":\.specialtyId,
    "city_id":\.cityID,
    "region_id":\.regionId,
    "name":\.name,
    "company_id":\.companyId,
    "order_by":\.orderBy]
}
```

```
private var parameters: Parameters? {
    switch self {
        case .searchForDoctors(let doctorsFilter):
            return doctorsFilter.parameters()
        case .someOtherThing(let someOtherThing):
            return someOtherThing.parameters()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The other approach is to simply split your creation of the `parameters` dictionary into multiple lines; If you assign `nil` against a dictionary key then there is no key/value pair stored in the dictionary for that key. In this case I have left your tuple approach in place, but you could use the struct (and I strongly suggest you do so)

```
private var parameters: Parameters? {
    switch self {
        case .searchForDoctors(let doctorsFilter):
            var params: Parameters()
            params["main_category_id"] = doctorsFilter.0
            params["page"] = doctorsFilter.1
            params["specialty_id"] = doctorsFilter.2
            params["city_id"] = doctorsFilter.3
            params["region_id"] = doctorsFilter.4
            params["name"] = doctorsFilter.5
            params["company_id"] = doctorsFilter.6
            params["order_by"] = doctorsFilter.7
            return params
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

If we want to handle mixed properties, rather than just optional strings, we need to modify the code slightly. We need to use `PartialKeyPath`.  This makes the code a little more complex since the subscript operator for a `PartialKeyPath` returns a double optional.  This needs to be handled.

```
protocol Parameterable {
    var paramNames: [String:PartialKeyPath<Self>] {get}
    func parameters() -> [String:Any]
}

extension Parameterable {
    func parameters() -> [String:Any] {
        var parameters = [String:Any]()
        for (paramName,keypath) in self.paramNames {
            let value = self[keyPath:keypath] as? Any?
                if let value = value { 
                    parameters[paramName] = value
                }
        }
        return parameters
    }
}

struct DoctorsFilter:Parameterable  {
    var mainCategoryId: String?
    var page: String?
    var specialtyId: String?
    var cityID: Int
    var regionId: String?
    var name: String?
    var companyId: String?
    var orderBy: String?
    let paramNames:[String:PartialKeyPath<Self>] =     
        ["main_category_id":\Self.mainCategoryId,
         "page":\Self.page,
         "specialty_id":\Self.specialtyId,
         "city_id":\Self.cityID,
         "region_id":\Self.regionId,
         "name":\Self.name,
         "company_id":\Self.companyId,
         "order_by":\Self.orderBy]
}
```

Comment: Perfect! this answer works with String values, but what if my parameters include Int values and String values

Comment: I have actually worked out that solution, but I didn't post it because it isn't quite as elegant; you have to handle some double optionals that arise when you use `AnyKeyPath`. I will update my answer later.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and I need the solution, hope you update your answer soon. thanks

Comment: I did; it’s at the bottom, using `PartialKeyPath`

Answer (score 1):

There are three primary ways to safely unwrap an optional. You can also provide default values if you wish to unwrap an optional.

#### Guard Statement Unwrapping

```
var firstString: String?

// In some cases you might performa a break, continue or a return.
guard let someString = firstString else { return }
print(someString)
```

#### If Let Unwrapping

```
var secondString: String?
var thirdString: String?
thirdString = "Hello, World!"

// Notice that we are able to use the same "IF LET" to unwrap
// multiple values. However, if one fails, they all fail. 
// You can do the same thing with "Guard" statements.
if let someString = secondString,
   let someOtherString = thirdString {
       print(someString)
       print(someOtherString)
} else {
       // With this code snippet, we will ALWAYS hit this block.
       // because secondString has no value.
       print("We weren't able to unwrap.")
}
```

#### Default Value Unwrapping

```
var fourthString: String?
// The ?? is telling the compiler that if it cannot be unwrapped,
// use this value instead.
print(fourthString ?? "Hello, World")
```

In Swift it is recommended that anytime you see a `!` that you use some form of unwrapping. Swift is very "Type Safe".

Here's a resource you can use for Optionals.
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

#### Your Solution

Your solution might look something like this.

```
private var parameters: Parameters? {
   switch self {
   case .searchForDoctors(let doctorsFilter):

       if let mainCatID = doctorsFilter.0,
          let page = doctorsFilter.1,
          let specialtyID = doctorsFilter.2,
          let cityID = doctorsFilter.3,
          let regionID = doctorsFilter.4,
          let name = doctorsFilter.5,
          let companyID = doctorsFilter.6,
          let orderBy = doctorsFilter.7 {

          params: Parameters = ["main_category_id": mainCatID, 
                                "page": page, 
                                "specialty_id": specialtyID, 
                                "city_id": cityID, 
                                "region_id": regionID, 
                                "name": name, 
                                "company_id": companyID, 
                                "order_by": orderBy]
          return params
    } else {
          //Unable to safely unwrap, return nothing.
          return nil
    }
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but you didn't get my question, I'm not asking how to safely unwrap optional values, I'm asking how to handle the optional values associated with specific situation

Comment: My answer, answers your question. Simply ignore the "Else" statement  or use a `guard let` in lieu of an `if let`. If you aren't able to unwrap, it will not step into that code block, thus allowing you to not add your kvp's.

Comment: please read my question carefully, I don't want to say if let for every optional value, also I don't want to provide default value. I'm looking for a simple way to add keys and values to dictionary without writing 10 lines of code to unwrap the optional values!

Comment: @ZiadKamel then you're asking for something called "Force Unwrapping" which will cause your app to crash. You MUST unwrap them, which is convention. Otherwise in your doctorsFilter class, you need to make sure that those values aren't optionals.

Comment: making a function that handles the dictionary and returns it in DoctorsFilter class is an option. I'm thinking of adding this function to the APIRouter, is it fine to add it there? is it the rule of the APIRouter to handle the parameters ? or the APIRouter just interested in taking the parameters and will not handle it ?

Comment: I would say that where you put it, is up to you. There's no convention for where you handle data, with the exception of some coding standards provided by your company, or standards you might follow. The general rule of thumb is, if it works, don't mess with it.